# What does "夢プチ" mean?

Tags: meaning, words, definitions

I'm reading a manga in which a character mentions the following to another character:

> 今月の"夢プチ"見たよ

I'm assuming that "夢プチ" is a play on something but I can't find anything via Google. Both characters are children too so I would assume it's a reference to some Japanese kids thing?

Comment: "I watched/saw 夢プチ of this month", this suggests that 夢プチ is a types of monthly magazine, TV show or something. I couldn't find this word on the real internet, perhaps It's a fictional thing.

Comment: Yeah it being a fictional magazine seems like it'd probably make the most sense. I suppose it could be a mix-up of Petite Comic (プチ) and Hana to Yume (ゆめ/夢).

Comment: Could you by any chance tell me which manga it was?

Answer (score 2):

夢プチ must be something that is produced only once a month like magazine and since 
you just read it from manga, it might be that the author just made it up and it doesn't exist in real world that's why theres no result from internet and nobody is talking about it but us. youve been reading that manga so you should have known something more than anyone here. and i think it wouldn't hurt if you mentioned the manga title.